# C: How to include the squash compression library?

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to programming with c and i am having a hard time including the [squash](https://github.com/quixdb/squash) library into my program.

I cloned the repository and ran `./configure` and `make` `sudo make install`.

That installed the files:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/squash-0.8.pc
/usr/local/lib/libsquash0.8.so.0.8
/usr/local/lib/libsquash0.8.so.0.8.0
/usr/local/lib/libsquash0.8.so
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Squash-0.8.0/SquashConfig.cmake
/usr/local/bin/squash
```

And some more files in this directories:

```
/usr/local/include/squash-0.8/
/usr/local/lib/squash/0.8/plugins/
```

In the squash examples the library is included by `#include <squash/squash.h>` but when i am trying to compile it i get `fatal error: squash/squash.h: No such file or directory`

Also `#include <squash-0.8/squash.h>` doesnt work because then i get `fatal error: hedley/hedley.h: No such file or directory` That file is located at 
`/usr/local/include/squash-0.8/squash/hedley/hedley.h`

I guess the solution is pretty simple for an experienced c programmer but i am failing here..

Do i need to set some sort of environment variable to let the compiler find the library?

And how do i link the library to the compiler anyway? 
I found something like:

`-rdynamic ../squash/libsquash0.8.so.0.8` but could not test it yet because of the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
#include <squash/squash.h>
```

to

```
#include "squash/hedley/hedley.h"
```

or

```
#include "<squash-0.8/squash/hedley/hedley.h>"
```

easier and faster solution would be adding the path to your includes during compilation:

```
-I/usr/local/include/squash-0.8/squash/
```

Comment: I tried that but that cant be the solution. In the main header file `squash.h` are a lot more headers that are included like the `hedley.h` so i would have to rename 10+ header files in the `squash.h` file. I doubt thats the intended way to make the library work.

Comment: You can tell your compiler to add the path to the squash-includes to its default include paths.

Comment: @Crocboss see edit: you can make your compiler look for header files in squash-0.8/squash/ as Paul has pointed out.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I copied the `squash` directory from the repository, which includes the `squash.h` and all other necessary headers like `hedley/hedley.h`, into a `lib/` directory in my project and ran the compiler with `-Ilib -rdynamic lib/squash/libsquash0.8.so.0.8` and it works!